# Hide an element off the screen when it reaches the edge of another element

Tags: html, css, position, css-position, adaptive-design

I have about the same structure. The width of the central content part is 1080px. `.corner` is an angle with absolute positioning that cuts off the right side of the header.

The problem is that when the screen narrows, this angle goes to the content part. I will hide it from mobile devices altogether, but on other resolutions I would like it to just go off the screen when it rests on the left side of the content part.

```
<div class="header">
    <div class="corner"></div>
    <div class="header-content">
        Some kind of header content
    </div>
</div>
<div class="main">
    <div class="content">
        Some kind of main content
    </div>
</div>
```

My CSS

```css
.header {
    max-width: 1080px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: #FAAC38;
}
.corner {
    width: 253px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    border: 0 solid #f8f9fa;
    border-bottom-width: 168px;
    border-top-width: 0px;
    border-left: 168px solid #FAAC38;
}
.main {
    max-width: 1080px;
    margin: 5px auto;
    padding: 60px;
    background-color: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #e9ecef;
}
```

I made a gif

[image]

Comment: Could you please share the css file(s) you are using?

Comment: Added some styles to the question.